# Rtmidi set callback non static member function

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that needs control over multiple Midi devices.
My code looks like this:

```cpp
void Device::openInputPort(const std::string& deviceName) {
    try {
        for (unsigned int index = 0; index < input->getPortCount(); ++index) {
            std::cout << input->getPortName(index) << '\n';
            if (input->getPortName(index).rfind(deviceName)) {
                input->openPort(index);
                input->setCallback(&Device::inputCallback);
                std::cout << "Found input device\n";
                break;
            }
        }
//        input->ignoreTypes(false, false, false);
    }catch (RtMidiError &error){
        error.printMessage();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

I want to pass a member function of the device class as a callback to the RtMidiIn.
How would I accomplish this?
I already tried to use `std::bind` passing a `this` pointer as well and tried to use a lambda too, but nothing was working.

Answer (score 0):

If setCallback accepts a C like function pointer then you cannot pass a member function pointer instead.

Like int and string they are two different things. Member function requires a this pointer as one of its parameter while a c like function don't.

So if setCallback accepts a function pointer, probably a solution is to create a hashmap and then from the common callback function get the corresponding instance of device and call a member function from the device instance.

Comment: As RtMidi is written in c++ I would most certainly expect it to take a C++ function pointer. It states on its Github page that it is a set of c++ classes that provide a common interface to work with midi on all platforms. I also passes a vector pointer to the callback.

Comment: Let me tell you again, C/C++ function pointer and C++ member function pointer are different things. So please check the parameter type of setCallback

Comment: I have no experience with RtMidiIn. So I hope the link I am sharing is the right one. Please see the link there a C/C++ function pointer is given to setCallback and not C++ member function pointer https://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/